# crontab doesn't execute his jobs

Tags: linux, cron

I have a problem with executing `crontab` jobs. I guess I have everything configured properly but when i put:
`*/2 * * * * /var/www/site/executescript.sh` in 
`crontab -e`
 My script is not being executed at all.. Only thing i get in `cron.log` is:

```
Feb 15 10:22:35 server crontab[2222]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Feb 15 10:22:45 server crontab[2222]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Feb 15 10:22:45 server crontab[2222]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Feb 15 10:26:24 server crontab[2329]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Feb 15 10:27:17 server crontab[2329]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Feb 15 10:27:17 server crontab[2329]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Feb 15 10:29:34 server crontab[2415]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Feb 15 10:29:53 server crontab[2415]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Feb 15 10:29:53 server crontab[2415]: (root) END EDIT (root)
```

What mean that cron doesn't even try to execute my script. Do anyone knew what is this related to? Does it mean there is an error in my script ( i don't see one..) Is there a place where i can check more accurate cron logs?

Version of my cron is v5.0

Comment: Have you tried sending SIGHUP manually to the cron deamon with `kill`?

Comment: No i did not, I am kind of newbie in matter of operate on linux, what am i suppose to `kill`?

Comment: First, make sure that cron is running.

Comment: Does the script have the executable bit set?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the binary executing the script. Try with this:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/site/executescript.sh in
```